# Can I get at attributes of individual elements that JQuery selects during selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am using JQuery and the JQuery UI Slider to render some controls in my HTML page and I want to set the range of the slider from an attribute in my HTML.

Here is the code I use to initialize the sliders...

```
$( ".slider" ).slider(
  {
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    slide: handleSlide
  }
);
```

Of course the max value is hard coded.  What I would like to do in my code is...

```
<div class="slider" id="sliderA" max="10"></div>
```

but I can't figure out how to get at an attribute during selection.

I thought I may have access to it via `this`, like you do in JQuery's `.each()` but firebug tells me it is the document, so that doesn't work.

I want to do something like...

```
$( ".slider" ).slider(
  {
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: blah.getAttribute("max"),
    slide: handleSlide
  }
);
```

but I can't figure out what `blah` might be.

Is there an accepted way to do this?  I confess that JQuery still has a bit of black magic for me but I am working under the presumption that the selector resolves to an array of objects somehow, so it feels like I should be able to get at the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $( ".slider" ).each(function()
    {
     $(this).slider(
      {
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: $(this).attr("max"),
        slide: handleSlide
      }
    );
    });
```

Comment: what's the implication of using $(this) in the each?  It feels like I would be constructing a new JQuery inside a loop, which feels bad... or am I worrying about nothing?

Comment: Don't feel bad.You have no option but to use it if you don't want to modify the slider plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Your code creates a single object literal, then passes it to a `slider` method.  Inside the object literal, your outer `$` call does not exist.

Instead, you need to call `.slider()` inside of `.each`, allowing you to create a separate object literal for each element.
Also, since you'd be creating the object literal in the `each` callback, it would have `this` from the `each` callback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your best option is to get the value of your "max" attribute on the fly:

```
    $('.slider').each(function (index) {
        $(this).slider({
            max: $(this).attr('max'),
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                console.info(ui.value);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: this won't work because there is more than one slider with possibly different max values...

Comment: True, it won't. @SLaks' answer is right. I've updated my code to reflect his suggestion.